# Code with var variable at each level gives unexpected result

Tags: javascript, scope, settimeout, lexical-closures

Please provide an explanation why the output will be 4. I am trying to understand that the output is 4 but cannot find the reason why is it not 3.

```js
var x=4,
obj={
    x: 3,
    bar:function(){
        var x = 2;
        setTimeout(function(){
            var x=1;
            console.log(this.x);
        },1000);
    }
}

obj.bar();
```

Comment: `this` in the `setTimeout` callback is the global object, because this code is in loose mode rather than strict mode. It's also at global scope, so the `var x` at the top becomes a property of the global object. So `this.x` is `4` inside that callback.

Comment: I strongly recommend always using [strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode), either by A) Using [modules](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules), which are strict by default; or B) Putting `"use strict";` at the top of the file. Strict mode fixes several issues with the language, not least [implicit globals](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html) like your `obj` (the lack of declaration should make using it an error).

Comment: In strict mode, your code would fail with "TypeError: Cannot read property 'x' of undefined" because `this` inside the `setTimeout` callback would be `undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `this.x` inside the function of `setTimeout`, thus it is printing `4`, however, if you do not use `this.x` it shall print `1` to the console. You must remember that the `**this**` keyword behaves differently in JavaScript compared to other languages. In JavaScript, the value of `**this**` does not refer to the function in which it is used or its scope but is determined mostly by the invocation context of function `(context.function())` and where it is called.

As you see in the above example `**this**` in setTimeout function does not refer to the `lexical scope` of the function. But refer to `global scope` because it’s the invocation context of the function.